# "[SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]" Using Express for Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

The following works perfectly well for me:

```
app.get('/doi/meta/:doiName1/:doiName2', function(request, response) {

  var path = '/doi/json?doi='+request.params.doiName1+'/'+request.params.doiName2;

  // etc.
```

For instance, I can call:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1337/doi/meta/09.1010/9347426
```

and get the response I am expecting. (Note the name of the object I am querying has a slash.)

Because there is some potential variability in the object names, I have a need to alter the server so that I can structure my queries like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:1337/doi/meta?doiName=09.1010/9347426
```

I have tried numerous approaches, but I invariably receive the following response:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input]
```

which suggests to me that I am looking for the problem in the wrong place. However, I can change the server code back to the above and it works fine. My code currently looks like this:

```
app.get('/doi/meta', function(request, response) {

  //var path = '/doi/json?doi='+request.params.doiName1+'/'+request.params.doiName2;

  var args = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  var path = 'doi/json?doi='+args['doiName'];
  console.log('path is '+path);

  // etc.
```

The console.log statement is never reached. What is the issue that is causing this Unexpected End of Input error?

Comment: Why are you parsing `request.url` when Express already does this for you? Query parameters are available on the [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was that several hundred lines above in the same file there was another GET listener:

```
app.get('/doi/:user', function(request, response) {
```

This block was catching calls like:

```
http://localhost:1337/doi/meta?doiName=09.2815/4539580
```

and going to look for a user named meta. Naturally, this phenomenon did not occur when I structured the GET block like this:

```
app.get('/doi/meta/:doiName1/:doiName2', function(request, response) {
```

I am going to address this issue by "deepening" the first listener above to something like...

```
app.get('/doi/user/:user', function(request, response) {
```

Another lesson learned is to group similar URL calls together in the same file.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 12):

A `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error typically means either you are missing a closing parenthesis, brace, bracket, or similar character somewhere in your code or you are trying to `JSON.parse()` a string that is missing such characters.

Run your code/JSON string through a javascript linter (e.g. [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint)) to find syntax errors.